# Override the default build script for Android in IDEA?

Tags: java, android, ant, intellij-idea

I had imported the eclipse project to the IDEA and created my custom build.xml for Ant. It works fine, but I want IDEA to use my own build.xml instead of default, when I press "Build project". How can I do this?

Comment: Tell IntelliJ you want to add your build.xml - look at the Ant menu on the right and hit the plus sign to add a new Ant build.xml

Comment: Already done, but it uses the default script for Cmd+F9.

Comment: So just run the build without using cmd+F9.

Comment: It works, but I want to replace the default by my own, because it's not such efficient as pressing hotkey.

Comment: C'mon, man.  You're going to say that double clicking to run the Ant build is less efficient than the hotkey?  Please.

Comment: Of course, because if I click on the icon, I must do it on touchpad or on mouse. This switching takes a lot of time summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is not using any script to build your Android project by default. It uses a combination of sophisticated incremental Make system with Android tools in order to save time when building the project.

If you want to build the project with custom Ant script, just add it to the Ant build panel and run the required target from there.

Note that it's possible to **assign keyboard shortcut** to Ant build target in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: Assign Shortcut...]

Comment: +1 - Nice to know where to find a rep for the best IDEs on the market.  Thanks, Crazy Coder.